# By Central Limit Theorem, is this Normal?

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

Trying to understand Central Limit Theorem via example.

My question is,

> In a simple random sample of $1000$ physicists taken among all
>   universities in a country, the number of papers published by the
>   sampled physicists in the past year had a mean of $1.1$ and a standard deviation of
>   $1.8$.

In this example, does the Central Limit Theorem say that the distribution of the number of papers published by the sampled faculty in the past year is roughly normal?

I know that the sample mean is close to the population mean and can be considered as the population mean. The sample size is also quite large, and I assume it's large enough to say the means are distributed roughly normal by CLT. However, the standard deviation is large. I know that on a normal the standard deviation are $+ - 1$, but i don't know how to use the standard deviation given.

If it's not normal then what shape is it?

Comment: what does SD stand for?

Comment: standard deviation

Comment: The size of the standard deviation does not really matter very much for the normal approximation, mostly because it is "scaled out" of the problem when you take the normal approximation. Specifically the normal approximation tells you that $\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$. In your example, $\mu=1.1,\sigma=1.8,n=1000$.

Comment: The standard deviation of a standard normal distributed is $\sigma=+1$. It´s a unique number. The following is not right:"...on a normal the standard deviation are +−1".

Comment: Since the number of papers cannot be negative, it seems "the number of papers" cannot have a "roughly normal" distribution.

Answer (score 3):

There's no telling what distribution the number of papers per person has. That is not what the theorem is about. Here's the point. Since each value in the data set is a random variable, the sample mean $\overline{X}_n$ is itself a random variable, with an approximately normal distribution provided the sample is large. More precisely, when the sample size $n$ goes to infinity, $$\sqrt{n}\,\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}\sigma\to N\left( 0,\,1\right)$$

Comment: Please leave a comment if you downvote. I neutralized the downvote by upvoting.

Comment: I'm confused, if we suppose the number of papers published by the sampled faculty in the past year are i.i.d. and we let $S_n$ be the sum of all or i.i.d events, $X$, then the total number of papers published by the sampled faculty in the past year is roughly normal with mean = $1000 \cdot 1.1$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{1000} \cdot 1.8$. Is this not true by Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: @callculus "Neutralizing" downvotes (or upvotes) by upvoting (or downvoting) is a bad idea, as common sense indicates and as has been discussed several times on meta.

Comment: @Did Sorry, I haven´t known that. But what I know is that it has been discussed the topic downvoting without leaving a comment. Could it be changed  or it is technical impossible ?

Comment: @callculus Yes it was discussed, and the suggestion reappears periodically, with each time the conclusion that it would be impractical. In fact applying it would be a sure way to destroy the SE vote system. (As an aside, let me ask you this: would you be adamant as well that upvoters should leave a comment explaining each of their upvotes? If not, why?)

Comment: @callculus For example, in the present case, upvoters should explain why they think that the sentences "if I pick people at random, the average performance is itself random" and "the sample mean is approximately Normal, provided the sample is large" are useful, although, in every meaning I can give to them, they seem wrong (no, "the sample mean" is not "approximately normal", only the deviations of the sample mean from the mean are, if suitably renormalized).

Comment: @Did Given that $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\approx N\left( 0,\,1\right)$, why do you object to the approximation $\bar{X}\approx N \left( \mu,\, \frac{\sigma ^2}{n} \right)$?

Comment: Because the first formulation in your comment is correct while the second one is not. If one insists on stating that $\bar X_n$ converges in some sense, one should stick to the (true) result that $\bar X_n\to\mu$ almost surely. If one wants to state a CLT, one should look at the renormalized $\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)$.

Comment: @Did My comment was never about convergence, only about the approximation that follows from it, which is what $\approx$ denotes. Ditto with my answer. The OP wanted to know whether the distribution is Normal (which is a common approximation); I said no, the sample mean is approximately Normal. Restating the convergence result is less likely to correct the misconception than explicitly drawing that contrast.

Comment: The trouble with the statement in your previous coment is that one should give a precise sense to the sign $\approx$ -- and then chaos ensues. To wit, the natural meaning of $U_n\approx V_n$ when convergence in distribution is involved is that $P(U_n<x)\sim P(V_n<x)$ for every fixed $x$, when $n\to\infty$. But then $\bar X_n\approx N(\mu,\tau_n^2)$ for every $\tau_n^2\to0$, not only $\tau_n^2=\frac{\sigma^2}n$... and actually $\bar X_n\approx Y_n$ for every sequence $(Y_n)$ with mean $\mu$ and vanishing variances. So, what is left of the assertion that ...

Comment: ... $\bar X_n\approx N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}n)$, one wonders. The other assertion I mentioned (which you do not comment on), stating that "if I pick people at random, the average performance is itself random", is bizarre as well since "the average performance" seems to refer to $\bar X_n$, but then, again, $\bar X_n$ is asymptotically *deterministic*, not random... In both cases, the confusion comes from insisting on stating an approximation result for $\bar X_n$ itself, not for $\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)$. I am well aware that this (mis)step is often taken in (some) statistics courses ...

Comment: ... but, first, it is not rigorous, and second, it misleads the students -- hence my suggestion to avoid it altogether.

Comment: @Did I've edited viz. this suggestion.

Comment: Note that the correct normalization is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$, not $\sigma \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @Ian No, actually it is $\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)$.

Comment: @Did I am talking about in the denominator of the test statistic (so that in the end you wind up with multiplying by $\overline{X}_n-\mu$ by $\sqrt{n}$ as you say). In other words you have either $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ or $\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ as the test statistic. This is a common source of confusion (for example when talking about the normal approximation of the binomial). I tend to suggest that people don't memorize it, and just remember it as "shift and rescale so that the test statistic has mean zero and variance $1$".

Comment: At any rate, what is going on here is exactly like what happens in calculus. To leading order in $n^{-1}$, $\overline{X}_n$ is just $\mu$. The first correction to its distribution is described by CLT. To see this first correction through a limiting process, you must first subtract off the leading order term and then divide by the scale of the correction. This is just like how in calculus, to see the first order correction to $f(x+h)$ in $h$, you have to subtract off $f(x)$ and divide by $h$.

Comment: @Ian Quite relevant analogy. (I corrected the wrong normalization in the post.)